# Friendly URL with Apache Mod-Rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Been reading about this for a while now and I'm close but struggling with the final hurdle.

I have a url like this: 
site.com/detail/123/some-description/maybe-some-more-description

that I want to become

site.com/details.php?id=123

I've got this so far

```
RewriteRule detail/(.*)/.*$ details.php?id=$1
```

which according to this (https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) results in

details.php?id=123/some-text

how do I get rid of the some-text on the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- The regex: `(.*?detail)\/(\d+)\/.*`
- The replacement: `$1.php?id=$2`

Which results in `site.com/detail.php?id=123`.

They both can be tested at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5hniR0/2).

- `(.*?detail)` matches the site base URL with `details` and captures to the group `$1`.
- `\/` matches the slash itself (must be escaped).
- `(\d+)` matches the number and captures it to the group `$2`.
- `\/.*` matches the rest of the URL and it helps to not include it in the replacement.

Edit: Do you mind the difference between `detail` and `details`?

Comment: Cool I think that does it. Don't think I need the first group, but this is essentially what I was looking for: detail\/(\d+)\/.*

Comment: So I've added this into Wordpress, which has generated the following in the .htaccess RewriteRule ^(.*)\/details\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\/.* /detail/?id= [QSA,L] which doesn't seem to be working i can see it matches here https://regex101.com/r/5hniR0/3

Comment: It seems ok here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=7fe95f0b-48fc-5b3c-a296-3bfdbaa92052 but doesn't seem to be working when I run it locally through Apache / Wordpress. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in your case you have one more group of `/text/`

Change your rule from:
`RewriteRule detail/(.*)/.*$ details.php?id=$1`

to

`RewriteRule detail/(.*)/(.*)/.*$ details.php?id=$1`

If you don't know how many slashes there are you can just use group with excluded slash `[^\/]*`:

`RewriteRule detail/([^\/]*)/.*$ details.php?id=$1`

Comment: thanks for your very quick response. So do you need to know the number of following slashes ? I can't say for example store what is in the first slash as $1 and ignore everything following it ?

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ file.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]

use in anchor tag

```
  <a href="details/<?php $id?>">
```

if you want receive value in variable $value = $_REQUEST['key'];